# bash - print id number on multiple lines in new txt file

Tags: bash, awk, printing, echo, cat

I am trying to concatenate multiple .txt files into one .txt file. Each individual file has one column with 178 rows and is tied to one particular person. I would like the concatenated file to have three columns: person's ID #; person's session #; value taken from the individual .txt file, e.g.:

1. desired output format (minus bullet points):

   ```
    1 1 000
    1 1 001
    ....
    1 1 177
    1 2 000
    1 2 001
    ...
    1 2 177
   ```
2. My current script prints the output with ID # and session # only printed on the first line of each person's 178 lines and the remaining 177 values printed to column 1 underneath the ID #, e.g.:

   ```
    1 1 000
    001
    002
    ...
    177
    1 2 000
    001
    002
    ...
    177
    2 1 000
    001
    ...
   ```

I would like help getting the ID # and session # next to each of the 178 rows taken from each person's individual .txt file, not just in the first row as it currently prints.

Code below:

```
for subject in 170; do
    for session in 1 2; do

        cd ${datadir}
            ts_SalienceNetwork=$(cat sub${subject}.txt | awk '{print $1}')

            echo -e "${subject}\t${session}\t${ts_SalienceNetwork}" >> concat_data.txt

    done
done
```

Comment: how does `subject in 170` print as 1 in your output?

Comment: karakfa, apologies for the confusion. It does not print "1", it prints the correct subject # for each of the individual data files it grabs the data values from (170 to 192).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$t_SalienceNetwork` contains the entire file, and you're just putting the other variables before it, not before each line.

Use `awk` to print the first column of each row preceded by the variables on each line, no need for the variable.

```
cd "$datadir" # no need to do this each time through the loop
for subject in 170; do
    for session in 1 2; do
        awk -v subject="$subject" -v session="$session" '{printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", subject, session, $1)}' "sub$subject.txt"
    done
done >> concat_data.txt
```

Comment: You could code the session loop in Awk too.  Processing different subjects would be fiddlier — that loop is probably best left in the shell.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I am new and appreciate the help. I will be looping through multiple directories, each w/ their own file, which is why I had cd $datadir/$subject within the for loops. The ts_SalienceNetwork variable holds the data from the individual's sub${subject}.txt, I am then printing to concat_data.txt. In the concat_data.txt file, I would like the first two columns to indicate which participant and session each data point belongs to, each person and each session will have 178 rows. Will your suggestion still work for this setup? Thanks!